# Textarea adding extra spaces in MYSQL update

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, textarea

I have a textarea for an address within a CMS module - when I update the text it adds extra spaces to it in the database. All I am doing is adding text to the initial line, pressing Enter to add the new line.

Each time I update it seems to add extra spaces, any ideas why?

P.S I should note I am using Codeigniter v2

Comment: Looks like a windows/unix linebreak issue. On the one a linebreak = `LF+CR`, on the other it's just `LF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able `trim()` the textarea data before you add it to the db.

```
$data = trim($this->input->post('textarea_field'));
```